# Create Multilevel DataFrame by reading in data from multiple files using read_csv()

Tags: python, pandas

I have 10 files with the following identical format and column names (values are different across different files):

```
    event_code  timestamp   counter
0   9071        1165783     NaN
1   9070        1165883     NaN
2   8071        1166167     NaN
3   7529        NaN         0.0
4   8529        NaN         1.0
5   9529        NaN         1.0
```

Due to the nature of the files, I am trying to store these data in multilevel dataframe like the following: (Eventually, I would want the `box_num` level to go all the way to 10)

```
box_num                1                                 2                ...   
col_names   event_code  timestamp   counter |event_code timestamp   counter
      0     9071          1270451     1     |   8529       NaN       1    ...
      1     9070          1270484     0     |   9529       NaN       0    ...
      2     9071          1270736     1     |   5520       3599167   2    ...
      3     9070          1272337     3     |   7171       3599169   1    ...
```

I initially thought I could make a multilevel dataframe with a dictionary using the keys as the hierarchical index and the dataframe as the subjugated dataframe

```
col_names = ['event_code','timestamp', 'counter']

df_dict = {}
for i in range(len(files)):
    f = files[i]  # actual file name
    
    df = pd.read_csv(f, sep=":", header=None, names=col_names)
    df_dict[i+1] = df   # 'i+1' so that dict_key can correspond to actual box number
```

But I soon realized that I can't create a multilevel index or dataframe from a dictionary. So to create a Multilevel Index, this is what I did, but now I am stuck on what to do next...

`(box_num, col_list) = df_dict.keys(), list(df_dict.values())[0].columns`

If there are other more efficient, concise ways to approach this problem, please let me know as well. Ideally, I would like to create the multilevel dataframe right after the for loop

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use a pivot table or the pandas groupby function for this task. Neither will give you exactly what you have requested above, but it will be simpler to use.

Using your code as a starting point:

```
col_names = ['event_code','timestamp', 'counter']
data = pd.DataFrame()

for i in range(len(files)):
    f = files[i]
    df = pd.read_csv(f, sep=":", header=None, names=col_names)
    # instead of a dictionary try creating a master DataFrame
    df['box_num'] = i
    data = pd.concat([data, df]).reset_index(drop=True)
    data['idx'] = data.index
# option 1 create a pivot table 
pivot = data.pivot(index='idx', columns='box_num', values=col_names)

# option 2 use pandas groupby function
group = data.groupby(['idx', 'box_num']).mean()
```

Hopefully one of these can help you get going in the right direction or work for what you are trying to accomplish. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for the reply Denver. But I need a Multilevel Dataframe because the data from each file is unique and needs to be analyzed separately. More importantly, I would like to retain the index values since I require them to do analysis on timestamp data (for checking chronological order). Also wouldn't applying .pivot() or .groupby() aggregate the data? My end goal is to retain the unique individual values (and especially the original indices) for individual analysis, not aggregation.

Comment: In the groupby case it would remain unique because col_names is a group. Adding box_num to the groupby retains all information, but groups based on box_num as well. This would be transposed compared to what you are looking for. The pivot table also retains all the data. The top column would be box_num, the values would be all the data you are interested in, and the index would be col_names. I would try running both if you are not familiar with what the output of both those functions for your use case look like.

Comment: So I did try out the code before posting the first comment and for the pivot table, I got a KeyError due to `index='col_names'`. I assumed you meant the array col_names, so got rid of the quotes but this time I got a ValueError due to a mismatch in dataframe shape. Same was true for the groupby function - `'col_names'` caused a KeyError. When I got rid of the quotation marks I got a ValueError indicating that `Grouper and axis must be same length`

Comment: Oh I see, col_names isn't what you named your index, but rather you denoting the column names. Check my edit, 'col names' in the groupby and pivot function should be the index.

Comment: Hi Denver, so there were some issues with your code. 1) Because pd.concat() is in the for loop, the output `data` only returns data from a single file (last file in the loop) rather than concatenating the data from all the files. 2) Since you .reset_index(drop=False), creating `idx` column with `data['idx'] = data.index` is redundant. But I see what you mean that the pivot table/groupby will retain all the data. However, having such format would be difficult for the analysis I'm trying to do and actually I figured out how to create a multilevel dataframe using pd.concat(). I'll update my post.